# Learning Trail for Java Web Development?

Tags: java, jsp

I've Inheritted a large Java Web project which I've got to make some modifications to, I'm a fairly competent Java Programmer when it comes the the basics but I've never done any JSP programming or EJB  programming before. I remember vauguely doing some servlet programming 5 or so years ago in university, but I'm assuming that everything has changed since then.

I'd planned on getting myself up to speed this weekend, but I don't know where to start.

What would be a good learning trail to get me from Zero to proverbial Hero? or at least to a level of competency which will let me be able to read the JSP servlet and EJB code and understand how it works well enough to modify it and deploy it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ofcaurse it depends a lot on what project you inherited and when it was written.
Also what technologies are used?

The best resource on starting J2EE development I think it's the [Java Passion site](http://www.javapassion.com/j2ee/).

Answer (score 1):

The online tutorial on netbeans.org are very good. I recommend to download the NetBeans 6.5 IDE (free) and walk through the J2EE tutorials.
The tutorials are very well written, and introduce the basic elements of enterprise and web development. They also require very little time to complete.

http://www.netbeans.org/kb/

Comment: I'll have a look at it. We use eclipse at my company, but I'm sure I'll learn loads from using net beans.

Answer (score 0):

Find out how complex it is.  There is a vast difference between a web application without EJB's and one with.

Is it running in JBoss/Tomcat/Jetty/Resin/BEA/WebSphere?