# web development using java

Tags: java, jsp, web

I am learning java(J2EE) programming language these days. I wants to create a web-site having features where user can login, logout, post there comment and other features with time using java technology just as a hobby project.
But I don't have any idea from where to begin. It would be very helpful if some one just give some starting guidelines and tools needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If this is just for fun with no deadline, then I encourage you to go as low-level as you can by making servlets and jsp pages, and getting them to work with tomcat. Once you can get some hello world pages working, then start learning about other complementary technologies like Struts, and Hibernate, and the problems that they solve and the complexity that they introduce. Try to master one technology at a time (e.g. servlets) before going on to the next one. This way you can understand how technologies relate to each other and can avoid trying to climb multiple learning curves simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at this [tutorial.](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/) It pretty much explains everything that you need to know to build a website. Hope it might be of your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could start by learning to use the reference web framework which is JavaServerFaces.

Take a look [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/javaserverfaces-139869.html).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this tutorial http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/intro.html
When I was learning J2EE this tutorial was very helpful

This is good video tutorial http://www.vtc.com/products/J2EE-Java-2-Enterprise-Edition-tutorials.htm

Look at this [Learning Trail for Java Web Development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667308/learning-trail-for-java-web-development)

Answer (score 1):

Why not try [GWT](http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/webtoolkit/gettingstarted.html) ?

It's a top-level web toolkit (based on RPC), full-Java, easy to learn, intuitive, and well-documented.